# What's the Rails way to access the previous record in a series?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

Say I have a `Statement` model, which `has_many :months`. There are always 12 months associated with a statement, but *the first month can vary* (eg months = [Mar, Apr, May...Jan, Feb])

Given a certain month, what's the MVC way to find the previous month?

I find myself accessing it through the `statement` which feels dirty:

```
# statement.rb
has_many :months

def previous_month(month)
  if months.index(month) == 0
    return nil
  else
    return months[months.index(month) - 1]
  end
end

# blergh
prev_month = month.statement.previous_month(month)
```

Should I have a `previous_month_id` column in my database? How would you implement this functionality? I'm using Rails `2.3.x`.

Comment: MVC is a design paradigm dealing with the structuring of an application into three separate layers. This question deals with the M part and has nothing further to do with MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define it on the `Month` model to cut back on the roundtrips.

```
# month.rb
class Month < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :statement, :include => :months

  def previous
    return nil if self.index == 0
    find_or_create_by_index_and_statement_id(self.index - 1, self.statement.id)
  end

  def index
    statement.months.index self
  end
end
```

so that you can get `june.previous`. This should even work on unsaved records.

Comment: I don't think `self.index` will return the index of the month scoped to the statement, so it wouldn't be possible to tell if a given month was the first month or not using this approach.

Comment: I assumed from the question that `index` is used as the month number. (January: 0 thru December: 11). So it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that explicit. I've updated my question - the first month can be any month, and they cycle (eg [Nov, Dec, Jan ... Sep, Oct])

Comment: I don't think it does, unless you store the month's name (or index into array of month names), as well as an additional column storing the index of each month with respect to the `statement`. Eg if the first month is `Feb`, then it would have to be stored as `{ :name => 'Feb', :index => 0 }`. I think this is equivalent to my `previous_month_id` idea. Do you think this is the best approach?

Comment: There may be other ways depending on what you store with the `Month` model. Can you tell me what columns you have defined on `Month`?

Comment: The relevant columns are `id`, `name`, and `statement_id`. Month `belongs_to` Statement, and Statement `has_many` months. The month order is determined by their `id` column in the database; `statement.months[0]` will return the associated month with the lowest `id`.

Comment: I updated the answer. The `index` method is defined on the Month model now, and the belongs_to association with statement eager-loads the other months so that a call to the `index` method won't trigger another database query. I think this should work. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I've changed the find method to `find_by_index_and_statement_id`, as the 12 months are being created upfront.

Answer (score 0):

How are these months added? If they're added separately in the chronological order of the months then you can simply do what you have but you should define the order in the relationship.

```
#statement.rb

has_many :months, :order => 'created_at ASC'
```

If they're added some other way then you might need to think about having an order column and using [acts_as_list](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_list) to maintain the order.

Comment: They don't have an explicit `:order`; they are ordered by their primary key. What I have works - but is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To do this the MVC way, I would probably push this logic on the thing that 'owns' the statements. After all a statement usually belongs to something. After reading the comments though, it sounds like this is an inherited project. If not you have to ask why would you have a 'months' relationship, when the statement has a `created_at` column you can tie into? Here is what i came up with, it may not be helpful to you. Although do checkout `Date::MONTHNAMES` at the very least it sounds like that might be helpful to you.

```
describe User do
  before(:each) do
    @user = User.create!
  end

  it "should know about months" do
    Statement.create(:user => @user)
    @user.statements.last.month_name.should == "November"
  end

  it "should report last months statement as nil when there is no statement" do
    @user.last_months_statement.should be_nil
  end

  it "should report last months statement as nil if there is only one for this month" do
    Statement.create(:user => @user)
    @user.last_months_statement.should be_nil
  end

  it "should report a statement from the previous month if there is one"  do
    target = Statement.create(:user => @user, :created_at => 1.month.ago)
    Statement.create(:user => @user)
    @user.last_months_statement.should == target
  end

  it "should report last months statement if there a several" do
    Statement.create(:user => @user, :created_at => 1.month.ago)
    Statement.create(:user => @user)
    Statement.create(:user => @user, :created_at => 2.months.ago)
    @user.last_months_statement.month_name.should == "October"
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statements, :order => "created_at"

  def last_months_statement
    if statements.size <= 1 || statements.last.created_at.month < Time.now.month
      nil
    else
      index = statements.index(statements.last)
      statements[index - 1]
    end
  end
end

class Statement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def month
    created_at.month
  end

  def month_name
    Date::MONTHNAMES[created_at.month]
  end
end
```

Comment: To clarify, the `Statement` model `has_many :months` - each statement covers a 12 month period, starting on any month. There's additional associations with `months` that I haven't touched on, like `payments`. But `statement.months[0]` would return a `Month` object, not just a month name, and through it there are further objects that need to be accessed.

Comment: IMO months have days, not payments. Good MVC starts with good abstraction of the domain. Payments are made by users to pay of a balance that is described by the statement. The month is an irrelevant concept from that regard. Otherwise you have to really skew your logic when a payee pays more or less than the payment for the month. But, I'm not an accountant, so I defer to however you think is best. Good Luck.